# find the difference between 2 tables in oracle with different column numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 different sets of tables with 2 common columns.

Table 1 : STUDENT

| NAME | ID | DEPTID | YEAR | BATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 987 | 2020 | 2 |
| mno | 234 | 987 | 2020 | 2 |
| abc | 123 | 765 | 2020 | 2 |
| zyz | 124 | 765 | 2021 | 1 |
| abc | 123 | 986 | 2020 | 2 |

TABLE 2 : MAPPING

| ID | DEPTID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 765 |
| 234 | 987 |
| 123 | 986 |

Now, I am trying to find all details of table STUDENT which are not present table MAPPING .

Example

| NAME | ID | DEPTID | YEAR | BATCH | MISSING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 987 | 2020 | 2 | YES |
| zyz | 124 | 765 | 2021 | 1 | YES |

I tried using **Minus** but it works if columns are same .

Any help will be great .

Regards,

Abhay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an ordinary `NOT EXISTS`. Sample data till line #13; query begins at line #14.

```
SQL> with
  2  student (name, id, deptid, year, batch) as
  3    (select 'abc', 123, 987, 2020, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'mno', 234, 987, 2020, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 'abc', 123, 765, 2020, 2 from dual union all
  6     select 'zyz', 124, 765, 2021, 1 from dual union all
  7     select 'abc', 123, 986, 2020, 2 from dual
  8    ),
  9  mapping (id, deptid) as
 10    (select 123, 765 from dual union all
 11     select 234, 987 from dual union all
 12     select 123, 986 from dual
 13    )
```

---

```
 14  select s.name, s.id, s.deptid, s.year, s.batch, 'YES' missing
 15  from student s
 16  where not exists (select null
 17                    from mapping m
 18                    where m.id = s.id
 19                      and m.deptid = s.deptid
 20                   )
 21  order by s.name;

NAM         ID     DEPTID       YEAR      BATCH MIS
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
abc        123        987       2020          2 YES
zyz        124        765       2021          1 YES

SQL>
```